# Custom UITableViewCellEditingStyle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to create a custom `UITableViewCellEditingStyle`, say to change the the image/icon that appears next to each row and maybe what action it takes.

Is it possible and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check out the `editing` & `setEditing:animated:` and `willTransitionToState:` of [`UITableViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938). You will probably need a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: Thanks for that. Although I've found something that suits me that apple has already supported (although un-documented), the UITableViewCellEditingStyle multi-select, I'm sure this will help other people.

Comment: Huh, didn't know that existed (even if undocumented). That's cool. But you shouldn't use it! :)